# Time complexity of "add" from Apache Commons Lang class 'ArrayUtils'

Tags: java, arrays

I am wondering if this method of adding to primitive array is still constant time?

```
char[] arrayA = {'b', 'c'};
char[] arrayB = ArrayUtils.add(arrayA, 0, 'a');
// arrayB: [a, b, c]
```

Comment: Have you looked at the implementation? If not, why not?

Comment: @Michael all it says is this:  Copies the given array and adds the given element at the end of the new array. I do not know how to tell the answer to my question from that

Comment: I said the implementation, not the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the implementation [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html)

Basically in the end it uses `System.arraycopy` which has a complexity of O(n)